# Need a SQL query to search a database and delete rows with a specific value

Tags: sql

i need to do a search over a database and tables and delete the rows that contains a specific value.

So far i only have this query to only search in a database for a specific value and get a result:

[Narayana's Code http://vyaskn.tripod.com/search_all_columns_in_all_tables.htm](http://vyaskn.tripod.com/search_all_columns_in_all_tables.htm)

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? DB2? Firebird?

Comment: Normally that's just `delete from table where col = value`. What makes this more than a simple `delete`? Are you trying to search across multiple columns and tables? We need more information about your problem.